# How do I deploy envoy proxy as kubernetes load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

How do I create an envoy proxy as a load balancer to redirect the necessary traffic pods?

Here Kubernetes Service file

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: files
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: filesservice
  ports:
  - name: filesservice
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

And for the envoy configuration file

```
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.file_access_log
            config:
              path: /var/log/envoy/access.log
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/f" }
                route: {host_rewrite: files, cluster: co_clusters, timeout: 60s}
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router

  clusters:
  - name: co_clusters
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: LEAST_REQUEST
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: files
```

I have tried to change the cluster configuration to

```
   - name: co_clusters
     connect_timeout: 0.25s
     type: STRICT_DNS
     lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
     hostname: files.default.svc.cluster.local
```

However, none of this works, from the error logs am getting this outs

```
[2023-01-09 04:15:53.250][9][critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:117] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.clusters[0]) hosts: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
[2023-01-09 04:15:53.250][9][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:961] exiting
```

This is the [tutorial](https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-use-envoy-as-a-load-balancer-in-kubernetes/) I tried following but still no joy.

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to the changes made by the envoy during upgrades you can see that in this [issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/11119).

As I can see that you are following an outdated tutorial where the config may be different depending on the upgrades.

Attaching a newer version of the yaml file in the [git hub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/grpc-gke-nlb-tutorial/blob/HEAD/envoy/k8s/envoy.yaml), cross check with the existing yaml file with and note the changes. You can check that in the envoy website also by using this [doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-bootstrap-version).

Try the below yaml file and let me know if it works.

```
  listeners:
      - name: listener_0
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8443
        filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
              codec_type: AUTO
              stat_prefix: ingress_https

    clusters:
      - name: echo-grpc
        connect_timeout: 0.5s
        type: STRICT_DNS
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        http2_protocol_options: {}
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: echo-grpc
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: echo-grpc.default.svc.cluster.local
                    port_value: 8081
```

Note:added @type from reffering the links, so make changes if any required.

Attaching a similar [issue](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/20919) for your reference.

Comment: This answer is essentially just a collection of links.  What concrete action should the asker take; can you [edit] this answer so that it is self-contained?

Comment: @DavidMaze Added the yaml file for reference.

Comment: @Angwenyi have you checked the edited answer.